# Can I query TFS Discussion column?

Tags: tfs-code-review, tfs-query

I want to query the Discussion column of a TFS task.

I use Visual Studio 2012 Professional Edition. Now, I am only able to fetch entire history column. The 'Discussion' column which is inside of 'History' is not available when creating a new query.

As mentioned, every time my query returns entire History, I only want Discussion related data.
Please see attached screenshots of results returned by query . The 1st  screenshot with highlighted data in red is the data that I want.

[DiscussionColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lsl8O.png)

[HistoryColumn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN9Ck.png)